# Bitbucket Server REST Api change file

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

In the documentation from Bitbucket there is information about how to change file by Rest API:

> ```
> curl -X PUT -u username:password \
>      -F  content=@README.md  \
>      -F 'message=Updated using file-edit REST API' \
>      -F  branch=master \
>      -F  sourceCommitId=5636641a50b \
>      http://example.com/rest/api/latest/projects/PROJECT_1/repos/repo_1/browse/README.md
> ```
>
> **branch**: the branch on which the path should be modified or created
>
> **content**: the full content of the file at path
>
> **message**: the message associated with this change, to be used as the commit 
>   message. Or null if the default message should be used.
>
> **sourceCommitId**: the commit ID of the file before it was edited, used to identify if content has changed. Or null if this is a new file

But when I call my script:

```
curl -k -X PUT \
    -H "Authorization: Basic cnVhtrhjrthhtUUFaeHN3Mg==" \
    -F  content=@README.md \
    -F "message=Updated using README" \
    -F  branch=master \
    https://bitbucket.company.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/project_name/repos/repo_name/browse/README.md
```

I get this message :

```
Warning: setting file README.md  failed!

curl: (26) read function returned funny value.
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Correct request:

curl -X PUT -u username:password -F **content=Some changes** -F 'message=Updated using file-edit REST API' -F branch=master -F sourceCommitId=5636641a50b http://example.com/rest/api/latest/projects/PROJECT_1/repos/repo_1/browse/README.md

Content should be without @